# Problems with using execjs

Tags: javascript, python, pycharm, execjs

I use **execjs** call **js error**

```
execjs._exceptions.ProcessExitedWithNonZeroStatus: (101, '', "/var/folders/wd/2zd15m2d79j00
```

1. Executing with *VSCode* has no problems, but executing with *pycharm* has errors.
2. I have installed **node version 18**.
3. There is no problem executing this code: `execjs.compile('function test(page) {return {page: page}}').call('test', 1) #`